# Registry change permission remove other user rights

Tags: c#, registry, access-rights

I would like to change ownership, then permission to a registry key.

here the code I have so far :

```
        var id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();

        if (!Win32.SetPrivilege(Win32.TakeOwnership, true))
            throw new Exception();

        if (!Win32.SetPrivilege(Win32.Restore, true))
            throw new Exception();

        var hklm = RegistryKey.OpenBaseKey(registryHive, is64Key ? RegistryView.Registry64 : RegistryView.Registry32);
        using (RegKey = hklm.OpenSubKey(path, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.TakeOwnership))
        {
            if (RegKey == null)
                throw new Exception("clé de registre non trouvée");

            _security = RegKey.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);

            var oldId = _security.GetOwner(typeof (SecurityIdentifier));
            _oldSi = new SecurityIdentifier(oldId.ToString());

            _security.SetOwner(id.User);
            RegKey.SetAccessControl(_security);
        }

        using (RegKey = hklm.OpenSubKey(path, RegistryKeyPermissionCheck.ReadWriteSubTree, RegistryRights.ChangePermissions))
        {
            _fullAccess = new RegistryAccessRule(id.User, RegistryRights.FullControl, InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit | InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit, PropagationFlags.None, AccessControlType.Allow);
            _security.AddAccessRule(_fullAccess);
            RegKey.SetAccessControl(_security);
        }
```

Everything works fine, but in regedit, the subkey right only contains my user, all others users are removed.

Before :

[image: before change permission]

After :

[image: After change permission]

It seems that inherited rights are removed.

I'm close to succeed, it must miss a parameter, but I don't see which one.

Comment: Where is the initialization statement of _secTemp? As I know, you have get current access control, then modify it(add the new account) and save it using SetAccessControl(this method override the access control)

Comment: @OldFox sorry you're right, _secTemp is _security, I updated the code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding this:

```
_security.SetAccessRuleProtection(false, false);
```

Before you call this:

```
RegKey.SetAccessControl(_security);
```

Doing so will ensure that "protection from inheritance" is disabled (aka inheritance is allowed).

Comment: Thanks a lot ! in fact _security.SetAccessRuleProtection(true, true); works.